# ConstraintLayout weighted chain won't budge

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

For some reason, the weights for my ConstraintLayout items are not being applied. I've looked through the several times but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

[image]

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_scrollView_LL"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</ScrollView>
```

**Kotlin**

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sv, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val v = view
        val myCL = v!!.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.my_constraintLayout)


        val rlp1 = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)


        val r = context!!.resources
        val fourDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4f, r.displayMetrics).toInt()
        val tenDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10f, r.displayMetrics).toInt()


        /*
         * CardView items
         */
        val ivIcon = ImageView(context)
        ivIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_warning)
        ivIcon.setColorFilter((colorFTC), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        ivIcon.layoutParams = rlp1

        val tvText = TextView(context)
        tvText.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos aliquam vulputate percipitur ei."
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(tvText, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium)
        tvText.layoutParams = rlp1

        val cvMain = context?.let { CardView(it) }
        when {
            cvMain != null -> {
                cvMain.radius = fourDp.toFloat()
                cvMain.setContentPadding(tenDp, tenDp, tenDp, tenDp)
                cvMain.useCompatPadding = true
                cvMain.cardElevation = fourDp.toFloat()
            }
        }

        cvMain!!.id = View.generateViewId()
        ivIcon.id = View.generateViewId()
        tvText.id = View.generateViewId()

        myCL.addView(cvMain)
        cvMain.addView(ivIcon)
        cvMain.addView(tvText)

        // Constraint Set
        val set = ConstraintSet()
        set.clone(myCL)
        set.connect(cvMain.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, myCL.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0)
        set.connect(ivIcon.id, ConstraintSet.START, myCL.id, ConstraintSet.START, 0)
        set.connect(ivIcon.id, ConstraintSet.END, tvText.id, ConstraintSet.START, tenDp)
        set.connect(tvText.id, ConstraintSet.START, ivIcon.id, ConstraintSet.END, tenDp)
        set.connect(tvText.id, ConstraintSet.END, myCL.id, ConstraintSet.END, 0)
        set.setHorizontalChainStyle(ivIcon.id, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_PACKED)
        set.setHorizontalChainStyle(tvText.id, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_PACKED)
        set.setHorizontalWeight(ivIcon.id, 10f)
        set.setHorizontalWeight(ivIcon.id, 90f)
        set.applyTo(myCL)

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraints only apply to `Views` that are direct children of the parent `ConstraintLayout`. In your case, `my_constraintLayout` only has one child, which is a `CardView`. The `ImageView` and the `TextView` that you add using `addView()` are children of the `CardView` and not the `ConstraintLayout`, so the constraints you are trying to set have no effect on them.

You need to have a `ConstraintLayout` inside the `CardView` to add the `Views` and set the constraints.